# Android: Cannot start service from WidgetProvider

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-service

I'm trying to start a service from my widget provider to update the widget on orientation change. The problem is that the service does not seem to start. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? This is all I have in my code for now.

```
public class PSWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static Handler      handler             = new Handler();
    private static Runnable     runnable;
    public static int           currentAlarmSet     = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyUpdateService.class));

    }


    public static class MyUpdateService extends Service
    {
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            Log.i("MyUpdateService", "onStart");
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            // Update the widget
            RemoteViews remoteViews = buildRemoteView(this);

            // Push update to homescreen
            pushUpdate(remoteViews);

            // No more updates so stop the service and free resources
            stopSelf();
        }

        public RemoteViews buildRemoteView(Context context)
        {
            RemoteViews updateViews = null;

            updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_powersleep_layout);
            // Your code to build and update the remote view


            return updateViews;
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            int oldOrientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

            if(newConfig.orientation != oldOrientation)
            {
                // Update the widget
                RemoteViews remoteViews = buildRemoteView(this);

                // Push update to homescreen
                pushUpdate(remoteViews);
            }
        }

        private void pushUpdate(RemoteViews remoteViews)
        {
            ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(this, PSWidgetProvider.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.am.pn"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.1.7" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_p_s" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".receiver.PSWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED"/> 
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_config" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".receiver.PSWidgetProvider.MyUpdateService"
            android:process=":configservice"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try to change `context.startService(new Intent(context, MyUpdateService.class));` to `context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyUpdateService.class));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the service name should have read `android:name=".receiver.PSWidgetProvider$MyUpdateService"` 
since it is a static inner class.